# scanf function doesn't read doubles correctly

Tags: floating-point, double, scanf, dev-c++

In my homework, I have some problems with `scanf` function:

```
/* Can Doğu */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* My Function prototypes */
double calculate_profile_area(int edgecount,double edgelength); // Has two parameters: edgecount & edgelength. Returns double type value.
double calculate_volume(double a,double h); // Has two parameters: profilearea & boxheight. Returns double type value.
double calculate_price(double p); // Has one parameter: volume. Returns double type value.

/* My main function */
int main(void)
{

/* Variables & input-output part */
int count; double length,height,area,volume,price;
area=0.0,volume=0.0,price=0.0;
printf("Enter edge count for box profile: ");
scanf("%d",&count);
printf("Enter the profile-edge length and box-height: ");
scanf("%lf%lf",&length,&height);

/* Calling my functions */
area=calculate_profile_area(count,length);
volume=calculate_volume(area,height);
price=calculate_price(volume);

/* Printing the results */
printf("Box profile area is %.2lf cm square.\n",area);
printf("Box volume is %.2lf cm cube.\n",volume);
printf("Total sugar price is %.2lf TL.\n",price);
system("pause");
return(0);
}

/* calculate_profile_area function */
double calculate_profile_area(int edgecount,double edgelength)
{
double profilearea=0.0;
profilearea=edgecount*((edgelength*edgelength)/(4*tan(M_PI/edgecount)));
return(profilearea);
}

/* calculate_volume function */
double calculate_volume(double a,double h)
{
double v=0.0;
v=a*h;
return(v);
}

/* calculate_price function */
double calculate_price(double p)
{
double cost=0.0;
if(p>=0 && p<=500)
    cost=p*120;
else if(p>=501 && p<=1000)
    cost=p*100;
else if(p>=1001 && p<=2500)
    cost=p*80;
else if(p>=2501 && p<=5000)
    cost=p*65;
else if(p>=5001)
    cost=p*50;
return(cost);
}
```

When I enter a double value (2.15), my compiler reads it as 2.14999999.
Thus my 'area' result is calculated as 54.59 (which should be 54.60). Any idea why my result is not correct?

Comment: Please don't include pictures of your code, include the actual code in your question.

Comment: Please paste source code into your question as plain text (add proper formatting, of course). See also: [Discourage screenshots of cod and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: It's a pity that the title and body of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken make it about computation errors, but the accepted answer in its current form encompasses errors in conversion to/from decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: floating-point numbers are frequently not represented
exactly in computer systems. In general, computers use base 2, so a
number such as 2.15, with a fractional part of 3/20, will not be exact.

More details on this issue can be found in [“Why Are Floating Point
Numbers Inaccurate?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756). There is also Goldberg’s well-known paper on
the subject, [“What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic”](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse320/Documents/FloatingPoint.pdf).